# Как использоватся .join когда у меня есть список из списков

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Например имеется список:

```
[['1','2'],['3','4']]
```

Как превратить данный список в строку?

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Flattening a shallow list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/406121/4279)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
lst = [['1','2'],['3','4']]
s = ' '.join([' '.join(i) for i in lst])

print(s)
```

Результат

```
1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Можно избавиться от создания промежуточного списка строк, если использовать генератор: `' '.join(' '.join(i) for i in lst)`

Answer (score 4):

Для этого можно сначала развернуть список с помощью `itertools.chain.from_iterable`, после чего использовать `join`:

```
from itertools import chain

lst = [['1','2'],['3','4']]
print(' '.join(chain.from_iterable(lst)))  # 1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы напечатать список списков строк, объединяя строки через пробел:

```
list_of_lists = [['1','2'],['3','4']]
print(*map(' '.join, list_of_lists))
# -> 1 2 3 4
```

Если хочется строку получить:

```
>>> ' '.join(map(' '.join, list_of_lists))
'1 2 3 4'
```

Или, чтобы один раз `' '.join` вызывать:

```
>>> ' '.join([s for lst in list_of_lists for s in lst])
'1 2 3 4'
```

Если строки могут быть вложены глубже:

```
>>> nested_list = ['1', ['2'], ['3', ['4']]]
>>> ' '.join(flatten(nested_list))
'1 2 3 4'
>>> ' '.join(flatten(list_of_lists))
'1 2 3 4'
```

где:

```
def flatten(nested, isatom=lambda s: isinstance(s, str)):
    for item in nested:
        if isatom(item):
            yield item
        else:
            yield from flatten(item)
```

Comment: Можно немного упростить третий пример, если опустить создание промежуточного списка `' '.join(s for lst in list_of_lists for s in lst)`

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev: `[]` намеренно используется (`''.join` внутри в любом случае список создаёт, поэтому явный список помогает избежать создания ненужного промежуточного генератора).

Answer (score 1):

```
#И даже без всяких join. Если просто и по логике вещей. Куда уж проще.
ll = [['1','2'],['3','4']]
 ts = ''
 for i in ll:
     for j in i:
        ts = ts + j
```