# Как разделить все целые числа в массиве на отдельные разряды?

Tags: python

Доброго времени суток! Интересует такой вопрос.
Предположим, что существует вот такой код:

```
а = list(range(1,11))  
print(a)
```

Он будет выводить `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

Вопрос у меня такой: есть ли возможность каким-то образом разделить двухзначное число `10` на два отдельных элемента листа, т.е. чтобы по итогу лист выглядел так:
`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 0]`

Если интересует вопрос а "нафига" вообще это нужно, могу объяснить.
Задача следующая: составить список чисел от `a` до `b` (они задаются пользователем), затем посчитать сколько раз встречаются определенные цифры и вывести результат на экран.
Для определения цифр я использую функцию `count` (а-ля `b = a.count(1)`), но естественно цифра один встречается лишь один раз (что печально, но неудивительно).
Надеюсь на ваши советы. Возможно (а даже скорее всего), есть гораздо более легкий способ решения данной задачи, но мы легких путей не ищем.

**Всем спасибо за подробные ответы! Протестирую все представленные решения!**

Comment: Хм. А просто распарсить регексом и записывать в массив по разрядно религия не позволяет? Решения сверху относительно правильные и быстрые.
Только попадись длинное число или вообще отрицательное - все рухнет Нужны екзепшены

Comment: связанные вопросы: [Как разложить двузначное число на два однозначных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/516165/23044), [Как найти все дублирующиеся элементы в списке и количество их повторов?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/533108/23044)

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Как использоватся .join когда у меня есть список из списков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/592914/23044)

Answer (score 5):

Можно взять простое (в лоб), но не самое производительное решение:

```
input_numbers = [123, 987123, 0, 1, 2, 5]
output_digits = []
for number in input_numbers:
    output_digits.extend(map(int, str(number)))

print(output_digits)
>>> [1, 2, 3, 9, 8, 7, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 5]
```

Можно взять решение иное, сразу считающее цифры. Более красивое, на мой взгляд:

```
from collections import Counter

counters = [Counter(str(number)) for number in input_numbers]
result = Counter()
for counter in counters:
    result += counter
print(result)
>>> Counter({'1': 3, '2': 3, '3': 2, '9': 1, '8': 1, '7': 1, '0': 1, '5': 1})
```

решение это еще можно сократить, убрав массив счетчиков, сразу забирая элементы из начального массива - массив `counters` здесь для наглядности. Можно сократить и далее, сократив все решение до одной строки:

```
result = sum([Counter(str(number)) for number in input_numbers], Counter())
```

[Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects) очень быстр - у вас не возникнет с ним [проблем с производительностью](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/533108/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2/533121#533121), каким бы большим не был входной массив. Также помимо сложения, у счетчика есть и иные операции - загляните в [документацию](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects), чтобы ознакомиться - там есть и вычитание, и объединение (union) и много других интересностей.

Comment: более читаемо: `Counter(digit for digits in map(str, input_data) for digit in digits)`

Comment: по-моему использование `Counter` - наиболее идиоматически правильное решение для данной задачи +1

Comment: @jfs, по-моему можно несколько проще: `Counter(''.join([str(c) for c in input_data]))`

Comment: @MaxU по какому критерию это проще? Как по этому коду можно догадаться, что он частоты цифр считает в заданных числах. Явный цикл позволяет указать, что именно цифры считаются (я бы ещё `input_data` в `numbers` переименовал бы, чтобы не гадать что за данные).

Comment: @jfs, по-моему это очевидно. Ну можно еще вот так: `Counter(list(''.join([str(c) for c in input_data])))`

Comment: @MaxU: очевидно, что я не стал бы спрашивать, если бы ответ для меня был очевидным. Назовите хотя бы пару-тройку критериев, по которым вы считаете, что `Counter(digit for digits in map(str, numbers) for digit in digits)` является сложнее чем `Counter(''.join([str(c) for c in input_data]))`

Comment: @jfs, 1) по-моему, использование `list comprehension` является более предпочтительным по сравнению с  `map`. 2) зачем использовать второй явный цикл?

Comment: @MaxU: можно `Counter(digit for number in numbers for digit in str(number))` написать (чтобы от `map` избавиться, хотя когда *уже есть* именованная функция, то `map` вполне подходит -- меньше движущихся частей) 2- явный цикл используется, чтобы алгоритм был O(1) по памяти, а не O(n). 3- задача кода выразить намерение одного программиста другому (к примеру, самому себе, но через полгода). Осмысленные имена помогают. В этом второе достоинство цикла -- он позволяет явное имя дать (как я уже явно выше сказал в комментарии): видя `Counter(digit` я могу сразу сказать: код считает частоту цифр.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = 123456
b = map(int, str(a))
print b
```

или

```
b = []
while a > 0:
  b.append(a % 10)
  a = a // 10
b = b[::-1] # так можно развернуть, если бы нам был важен порядок
print b
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [69]: input_list = [1, 2, 456, 7, 8, 10]

In [70]: result = [int(x) for x in str(input_list) if x.isdigit()]

In [71]: result
Out[71]: [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 0]
```

Вариант с `regex`

```
In [88]: import re

In [89]: pattern = re.compile(r'-?\d')

In [90]: foo = lambda array: [int(value) for value in re.findall(pattern, str(array))]

In [91]: foo([1, 2, 10, 15, -23, -47])
Out[91]: [1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 5, -2, 3, -4, 7]
```

По поводу повторения, выше уже был вариант с `Counter`, предложу свой:

```
num_list = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3]
result = {
    num : num_list.count(num) for num in set(num_list)
}
print(result) # {1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

Доброго времени суток! 
Данный кусок "кода" работает только с указанным Вами примером.
Спасибо!

```
#Monkey code
a=list(range(1,11))
print(a)
#Вернет [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
#---------------------------------
#работает только с натуральными числами и нулем
#a="".join(str(a) for a in a) #соединяет массив в строку
#print(a)
#Вернет "12345678910"
#----------------------------------
#a=list(a) #разобьет полученную строку поэлементно
#print(a)
#Вернет ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '1', '0']
#----------------------------------
#a=list(int(a) for a in a) #Преобразует все элементы массива в int
#print(a)
#Вернет [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 0]
#----------------------------------
a=list("".join(str(a) for a in a))
a=[int(a) for a in a]
print(a)
```