# Как преобразовать список списков в список чисел (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, списки

Имеется:

```
[[1], [2], [3]]
```

нужно:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: `list(map(lambda x: x[0], a))`

Comment: связанный вопрос [Сумма элементов многомерного списка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/754233/23044)

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как использоватся .join когда у меня есть список из списков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/592914/23044)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
>>> a = [[1], [2], [3]]
>>> sum(a, [])
[1, 2, 3]
>>> a = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
>>> sum(a, [])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: можно упомянуть, что sum() ведёт к квадратичному алгоритму здесь (для сравнения [listcomp  из @tonal ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/871515/23044) это линейный алгоритм по числу чисел). Похожая проблема: [Непонятное замедление конкатенации в цикле](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/710117/23044)

Answer (score 14):

```
>>> a = [[1], [2], [3]]
>>> [x for l in a for x in l]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 8):

Ну или вот так:

```
from itertools import chain

list(chain.from_iterable(a))
```

Answer (score 6):

```
a = [[1], [2], [3]]
print([i[0] for i in a])
```

Answer (score 5):

```
result = []
for x in [[1], [2], [3]]:
    result.append(x.pop())
```

или

```
[x.pop() for x in [[1], [2], [3]]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Вариант через [functools.reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import add

items = [[1], [2], [3]]
print(reduce(add, items))  # [1, 2, 3]

# Через лямбду
print(reduce(lambda a, b: a + b, items))  # [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

еще вариант

```
outer = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
new_list = [item for sublist in outer for item in sublist]
```

получим

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Comment: Аналогичный ответ уже дали