# Как преобразовать подсписки списка в "плоские" списки?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Есть список вида:

```
[['aa', 'bb', ['cc', 'dd']], ['aa1', 'bb1', ['cc1', 'dd1']]]
```

Ожидаю получить:

```
[['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd'], ['aa1', 'bb1', 'cc1', 'dd1']]
```

Как решить эту задачу?

Comment: Расскажите, а что у вас не получилось? Как именно вы решали эту задачу?

Comment: пробывал вот эти варианты: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/871509/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb-python]

Comment: Эти варианты вам не подходят. Вам нужен просто цикл for по списку и базовая работа со списками (удаление элементов, сцепление списков): идете по списку, в каждом подсписке берете последний элемент (кладете в переменную), удаляете последний элемент из подсписка, и "присоединяете" этот элемент к подсписку через +=

Comment: _и "присоединяете" этот элемент к подсписку через +=_ не совсем понятна эта фраза

Comment: делайте +=, если очередной элемент подсписка - список, иначе - append (+= "разорвет" строку на символы)

Comment: @omatikaja у списка есть метод extend, который добавляет в список все элементы из переданного в метод списка. += - это то же самое по сути.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
my_list = [['aa', 'bb', ['cc', 'dd']], ['aa1', 'bb1', ['cc1', 'dd1']]]
new_list = []

for sub_list in my_list:
    tmp_list = []
    for el in sub_list:
        if isinstance(el, list):
            tmp_list += el
        else:
            tmp_list.append(el)
    new_list.append(tmp_list)

print(new_list)
```

выведет:

```
[['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd'], ['aa1', 'bb1', 'cc1', 'dd1']]
```

Answer (score 2):

Понимая пример из задачи буквально, буду считать, что все элементы исходного списка так выглядят (поэтому не проверяю, является ли последний элемент подсписка списком, и всегда беру последний элемент). Также буду решать прямо изменяя исходный список (что не всегда хорошо - особенно, если пытаться добавлять-удалять элементы списка, по которому идем циклом, но в данном случае количество элементов в общем списке не меняется, поэтому допустимо).

1. Идем циклом по списку, перебирая его элементы (подсписки)
2. Из каждого подсписка вытаскиваем последний элемент, записываем в переменную
3. Удаляем последний элемент из подсписка
4. Расширяем (extend) подсписок элементами из записанного в переменную списка

```
x = [['aa', 'bb', ['cc', 'dd']], ['aa1', 'bb1', ['cc1', 'dd1']]]

for sublist in x:
    temp = sublist[-1]  # Сохраняем последний элемент подсписка в переменную
    sublist.pop()  # Удаляем последний элемент
    sublist.extend(temp)  # Или sublist += temp - добавляем все элементы из temp в подсписок

print(x)
```

Вывод:

```
[['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd'], ['aa1', 'bb1', 'cc1', 'dd1']]
```

Comment: для "смешанных" подсписков (`[['aa', 'bb', ['cc', 'dd'], 'ee'], ['aa1', 'bb1', ['cc1', 'dd1'], 'ee1']]`) сработает не так, как ожидалось, я про это говорил (`[['aa', 'bb', ['cc', 'dd'], 'e', 'e'], ['aa1', 'bb1', ['cc1', 'dd1'], 'e', 'e', '1']]`)

Comment: @Jack_oS так в задаче и нет примера с такими списками. См. в начале ответа: понимаю пример буквально, а не придумываю все варианты, которые могли бы быть. Ваш вариант тоже не сработает, например, если в списке будет больше уровней, чем в примере, но и в условиях задачи про такой вариант ничего не говорится, поэтому его и не нужно учитывать.

Comment: ок, согласен: вариантов много, дедлайн - один ))